# Xamarin ProgressDialog

Tags: android, xamarin, progressdialog

I am building  `Xamarin` android app and I have a function that needs some time.
Now, I am  trying to display a `ProgressDialog` and execute the function. 
The code below do not show the `ProgressDialog`, I just see nothing. Can you please help me ?

```
private void BtButton_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{

    ProgressDialog mDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    mDialog.SetMessage("Loading data...");
    mDialog.SetCancelable(false);
    mDialog.Show();

    Task t = Task.Run(() => { Foo(); });
    t.Wait();
    mDialog.Dismiss();
}

private void Foo()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are blocking the main thread by invoking `t.Wait()`, more information can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd235606(v=vs.110).aspx).

Instead you can do something like this:

```
async void BtButton_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    var mDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    mDialog.SetMessage("Loading data...");
    mDialog.SetCancelable(false);
    mDialog.Show();

    await Task.Run((() => Foo()));
    // Alternatively
    // await Task.Delay(10000);

    mDialog.Dismiss();
}

void Foo()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

P.S.: `ProgressDialog` is deprecated in API level 26 use alternatives.

Comment: Thank you ver much this works. I did not notice that it is deprecated, than I need to look for an alternative

Comment: Glad to help. Good luck.